# How to replace str values by int values in a dataframe?

Tags: string, dataframe, integer

I'm new at programming and I'm working on a dataframe's column where I would like to replace all str values by the number '0'. This column has int values and str values, I want to replace the str values by 0 in order to remove it more quickly after. I tried to remove the values based on the their type but it didn't work, then, I'm trying a new approach now.

My following code doesn't return any errors but it doesn't work either..(my str values are still here and I don't know why...) :

```
for i in df['col_name'] :
 if i == df['col_name'].dtype.str :
     df['col_name'].replace([i], ['0'], inplace=True)
```

What am i doing wrong ? :/

Thanks for your help !

Comment: A dataframe can have only one dtype for all it's values. So if you want a totally integral column, Simply do `df['col_name']=df['col_name'].astype(int)`. And this will work only if all your column values are integers(represented as strings).

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for your anwser. It didn't completly help me but, thanks to you, I found how to solve my problem by using :
df['DataFrame Column'] = pd.to_numeric(df['DataFrame Column'], errors='coerce')
Anyway, thanks for your help and your time :)